# Creating Woocommerce Coupon Programmatically

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I'm trying to generate woocommerce coupon programmatically from my custom wordpress plugin.

Generally it works and creates coupon but some of coupon adding option still not works. For example Email Restrictions and Product Categories not adds on it. On $_POST it receives arrays on product categories and email restrictions but not works.

I also tried with and without implode() but same.

Here is my code:

```
function send_coupons_to_users_action() {
$couponname =   $_POST['couponname'];
$discountpercent = $_POST['discountpercent'];
$categorycount = count($_POST['categoryname']);
$usercount = count($_POST['checkedusers']);
$categoryname = $_POST['categoryname'];
$emailrestrict = $_POST['checkedusers'];

/* -------- GENERATE COUPON ------------ */
$discount_type = 'percent';

$coupon = array(
    'post_title' => $couponname,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
);

$new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

// Add meta
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $discountpercent );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'yes' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_categories', $categoryname );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit_per_user', '1' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', $usercount );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', '2017-05-09' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'email_restrictions', $emailrestrict );


echo 'Function End!';
}
```

What's wrong with it?

***** UPDATE *******

I solved this question. I'll post solution if someone need it.

1) I was trying to post category slug, but changed it with category id and it started working.

2) instead of :

`update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'email_restrictions', $emailrestrict );`

used:

`update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'customer_email', $emailrestrict );`

So it started working finally.

Comment: You can [edit] your question at any time to correct and update things. Comments are not good for that.

Comment: are you using woocommerce 3?

Comment: You can just create coupon with CSV import by using this plugin.https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-import-export-for-woocommerce/

Comment: @Reigel yes. It is updated woocommerce. I'm working on customer reward plugin.

Comment: @Mujeebu Rahman I'm working on my custom plugin. Anyway Thanks for reply!

Comment: In woocommerce 3, we now use set_props and save... please check https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/891e55e1cfc08697b88e24eef38f393f88718049/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-coupon-data.php#L346

Comment: @Reigel Thank you very much! I'll change my code.

Comment: I think that will solve your problem about `email_restrictions`. I've tried it and it works for me.

Comment: I solved my problem yesterday. I posted it as update. But i'll use new code i liked it.

Comment: yes, but your solution yesterday was that kind of a hack.. talking about woocommerce 3. `'customer_email'` is not `'email_restrictions'`

Comment: Can you post the finale solution or is this it? Does this work for Smart Coupons? Thanks a ton!